# Rails inventory (has_many through + left outer join)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Users (with name) can have cards (with name) through collections (with number):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :collections
    has_many :cards, through: :collections
end
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :collections
    has_many :users, through: :collections
end
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :card
end
```

I am trying to query Cards and getting how many a given user has (0 if he doesn't have the card), with:

```
Card.left_outer_joins(:collections).where(collections: { user_id: [nil, params[:user]] }).select("cards.*, collections.number AS number")
```

I get all the cards but I am missing the number field to know how many the user owns. What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the query to the one mentioned below:

```
Card.left_outer_joins(:users => [:collections]).
where(collections: { user_id: [nil, params[:user]] }).
select("cards.*, users.name ,count(collections.number) AS number")
```

In the above query , added a join for the user table to select their name and aggregate function to count the number of collections.

Modified the join relation as wanted to get to the collections via the user so that can be user specific.

Note: Please check the syntax for the nested of relations in the left outer join.